# Node.js/Express post method logging undefined in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here's my views upload.ejs page:

```
<%- include('header' ,{ title:"Playground" }) -%>
<div class="wrapper">
  <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Image Name">
    <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</div>
<%- include('footer') -%>
```

and this is my route upload.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../helpers/db');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('upload');
});

router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.name);
  res.render('upload');
});

module.exports = router;
```

After clicking the submit button, I get undefined in the console. If I try to console log req.body, I get empty {}.

Comment: Your form action is set to `"/upload"` and you are checkimg on on this post route `"/"`.

Comment: `router.post('/upload', .......)`

Comment: You're using `multipart/form-data` to send, but a URL-encoded parser to receive... Are you sure that's correct? Not least because the NPM page for `body-parser` says [it doesn't do mulipart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions).

Comment: Rather than stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, *turn on the lights* using a debugger. If you're using a recent version of Node, there's support for Chrome devtools built in. Perhaps the `console.log` output you're seeing isn't for the line you're editing (given the `/` vs. `/upload` thing...).

Comment: Thanks to T.J Crowder, the problem was found. Removing multipart/form-data to send fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that bodyparser doesn't parse the multi-part(Form -data) data. You will need to use another package for it (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Use multi-part request only when you are uploading files like image, documents. If you are using normal data then you can remove because multi part request is considered heavier than normal post request.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```